# How to convert linebased text to xml by valuelengths

Tags: java, xml-parsing, xsd-validation, text-parsing

I´ve got a textfile with X lines. Each line is representing one complete dataset. 
The structure of each line is like this:

```
 - Person A (Line 1)
   - Type (1 char)
   - Firstname (50 chars)
   - Lastname (50 chars)
   - Adress (50 chars)
   - ...
 - Person B (Line 2)
  - ...
```

**There are no seperators between the values.** Empty/Null values are just Y spaces for their amount of chars for their field.
So without spaces it could look like:

```
1WaltherWhiteAlbuquerque...
```

Now I want this as a *XML-File with X Nodes like [Person(Type,Firstname,..)]*.
Is is possible to write a template which "knows" the value-charlength and then pars it into xml format?

Comment: Your example is misleading because it doesn't match the fixed length fields. The field for firstname should contain "Walther" and 43 spaces. Read the file line by line and call [String.substring()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) to extract each field. You can use [String.trim()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--) to remove trailing whitespace.

Comment: This is why i said "without spaces look like..." and i know this way, but what´s the best way to say first part is type, second firstname, ... to genarate a xml file?

Comment: There is no best in general. It depends on what you want. For a small one-time script it can be the simplest to hardcode the fields. For a flexible generic way you can implement some field classes and read the configuration from a file. Or you can implement some annotations to create a class mapping like JPA for relational database tables. So make yourself clear what you want, then create the data model and implement the functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is is possible to write a template which "knows" the value-charlength and then parse it into xml format?

Sure.  In XSLT 3.0, something like this should work as the initial template of a stylesheet (not tested):

```
<xsl:template name="readfile">
  <xsl:variable name="lines" 
                as="xs:string*"
                select="unparsed-text-lines('mycolumnbasedinput.txt')"
                />
  <xsl:for-each select="$lines">
    <xsl:element name="Person">
      <xsl:element name="Type>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,1,1)"/>
      </
      <xsl:element name="Firstname">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,2,50)"/>
      </
      <xsl:element name="Lastname">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,52,50)"/>
      </
      <xsl:element name="Adress">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,102,50)"/>
      </
      ...
    </
  </
</
```

In XSLT 2.0, you'll need to read the input with unparsed-text() and split it into lines yourself using tokenize() or your method of choice.